# Extracting Verb Phrase from Sentence

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to extract verb and verb phrases from a column containing sentences for this purpose i have created a function called tagging. Here's my code:

```
pattern = [{'POS':'VERB'}]
def tagging(txt):
  verb_phrases = textacy.extract.matches(txt, patterns=pattern)
  return (verb_phrases)
```

and then i am applying this function a column from my dataset

```
dataset['Verbs'] = dataset['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: tagging(x))
dataset['Verbs']
```

But instead of returning me verbs, the output is like:

```
0      <generator object matches at 0x7f8eb98a5258>
1      <generator object matches at 0x7f8eb97df6d0>
2      <generator object matches at 0x7f8eb97df728>
3      <generator object matches at 0x7f8eb97df570>
4      <generator object matches at 0x7f8eb97df678>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the docs of `textacy.extract.matches`, this function does not `return` but rather `yield`s a Span and that's why you get generators.

```
    Yields:
        Next matching ``Span`` in ``doc``, in order of appearance
```

A common way of unrolling is list comprehension (`[generator]` / `list(generator)`) or iterating through it (`for item in generator:`)

**For your case:**

```
for verb_span in textacy.extract.matches(txt, patterns=pattern):
    print(verb_span)

verb_list = [verb_span for verb_span in textacy.extract.matches(txt, patterns=pattern)]
```

Comment: can you explain it to me through above mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pattern = [{'POS':'VERB'}]
def tagging(txt):
  verb_phrases = textacy.extract.matches(txt, patterns=pattern)
  return list(verb_phrases)
```